# Bus-hold circuit issue

Tags: microcontroller, voltage

We have a bus-hold circuit in one of the designs to hold the previous state of MCU GPIOs during Deep Power Down Mode when these GPIOs will be tri-state.

We are facing an issue in voltage levels when the bus-hold circuit is attached (in normal operation) to EN_1 and EN_2. The voltage levels of these two lines become 0.5 V when the bus-hold circuit is attached. They should be 3.3 V.

Please help us to solve this issue. What could be the reason the voltage goes to 0.5 V when bus hold is attached?

[image]

Comment: What is the value of R521 and R524? Are the "DNP" resistors really not populated?

Comment: @Mattman944 R521 and R524  are 0 ohm resistors, they are populated in the design.

Comment: You did not answer the second question. And is there any voltage drop over R909 or R910?

Comment: @CL. voltage drop over the R909 is 0.5V

Comment: So some other component (which is one of the DNP resistors, or not shown in the schematic) is sourcing or sinking 50 µA. You still did not answer Matt's second question.

Comment: @CL. Which DNP resistor? can you please mention that reference Designator? In the schematic whatever showing the DNPs are not populated in the design, they are optional.

Comment: R513, R520, R522, R523 are marked DNP on the schematic. Please confirm that they are not populated on your board. Look at the actual board, don't trust the schematic.

Answer (score 1):

When the MCU is powered down, the clamping diodes at its outputs pull the voltage down. (The MCU's absolute maximum ratings forbid voltages above V<sub>CC</sub> + 0.5 V.)

You have to disconnect the two MCU pins from the rest of the circuit while it is powered down. Use either

- a switch like the (SN)74LVC2G66, powered from VCC_3V3_OUT; or
- a buffer with overvoltage-tolerant outputs (called I<sub>off</sub>) powered from the MCU's supply (a second (SN)74LVC2G34 would work).